# vnc-server not installed on CentOS 6.4

Tags: centos6, vnc

while following [this Guide](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server) , i did this:

```
yum install vnc-server
```

and it installed success fully , but

```
rpm -q vnc-server
```

returns

```
package vnc-server is not installed
```

while

```
yum install vnc-server
```

says

```
Package tigervnc-server-module-1.1.0-5.e16_4.1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

also vncserver , vncpasswd and other vnc commands return command not found

centOS 6.4 is on a VPS (vmware) with KDE Gui

any clues to what should i check or what to do is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CentOS 6.x you need to install the `tigervnc-server` (not `tigervnc-server-module`) package.

On the CentOS Wiki (http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/VNC-Server) it's noted:

> If you are running CentOS 6, the server is: tigervnc-server not: vnc-server

Hope this helps.

Comment: yep , missed that one ... tnx